# How to use IScroll even though content is not overflowing?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, iscroll

I wonder if it is possible to use IScroll, more specific an angular version (github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll) even though content is not overflowing? So it would be possible to drag a non-overflowing list (see image below) and refresh the list with new content, for instance a list like the live demo version of IScroll (http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/).

I can't seem to find any options for this at the documentation, and could not find any solutions of how to do this?

Note: The content is of course dynamic so the height is dynamic as well.

Non-overflowing list:

[image]

Setting the height with 100vh for the wrappers child did the trick, but this actually breaks normal scrolling, as with 100vh IScroll sees no additional content to scroll to. So you cant scroll down a list that is overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a item with full height that is holding your target items.
this way the list is always 'overflowing'

Comment: Thx for your reply, not sure what you mean by an item with full height, the height was set to 100%, and did not work. But when i changed to 100vh it worked.

Comment: 100% is 100% of the parent height, i ment the 100vh sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: This actually breaks normal scrolling, as with 100vh IScroll sees no additional content to scroll to. So you cant scroll down a list that is overflowing. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: well if you place more content in the view that is 100vh its not considered a list item that can stretch behind de view boundaries. the trick is to make the containing views have 100vh together at minimum. you can try min-heigh:100vh;